# Alamofire 4 File Upload Parameter issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, afnetworking, alamofire

Plese have a look at the pic here from postman 
[POSTMAN success result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzpGW.png)
but the code does not run I am missing something please help me out

```
 var parameters = [String: String]()
        parameters = [
            "profile_image": "imagefile"
        ]

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]

        let url = "http://******/public/api/v1/profile/update-picture?api_token=" + "aySlC26ZTHtlnS0lhUpdghxkd9gKJBLXLYFUO2Jidmiisoka9iFIicwRIZFx"
        let completeUrl = URL(string:url)!

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage!, 1)
        print ("image data:: \(imageData)")
        print ("chosenImage:: \(chosenImage)")

//        Alamofire.upload(imageData!, to: completeUrl).response { response in
//            print (response)
//        }

        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { 
                multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(imageData!,
                                         withName: "imagefile",
                                         fileName: "image.jpg",
                                         mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!, withName: key)
                }
        },
            to: completeUrl,
            headers: headers,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON{ response in
                        print(response)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
```

[Postman Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO0pA.png)
Success on postman but having issue with headers, can you point out the silly mistake i have make

Comment: "the code does not run" ... what do you mean by "does not run"? Are you getting an error, and if so, what is the error? If it's not running at all, are you sure you're getting to the `responseJSON` line at all? Set break points and see where you're getting to and where you aren't getting to...

Comment: Also, as an aside, tools like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) are very useful for reconciling what the code is doing as opposed to what postman reported.

Comment: Unrelated, you generally don't have to manually set the `Accept` header. Alamofire does that for you.

Comment: I am getting response like i have issue with my parameters. The code runs but it does not upload picture

Comment: You're showing us the postman response. We should see what the successful request looked like in order to compare it to what your code would generate.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the comments, the issue was with parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to append the image this way

```
multipartFormData.append(imageData!,
    withName: "profile_image",
    fileName: "image.jpg",
    mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

And you don't need to set or include `parameters = ["profile_image": "image file"]`

As @rob mentioned, use Charles and compare the request from Postman with the request from the simulator.  It will help to pinpoint what's different

Comment: thank you, It was due to my own ignorance, setting the **withName** solved my problem. thanks